# Stack Overflow API: Finding the UserID of a user with their Display Name

Tags: discussion, users, api, screen-scraping

Hi! I'm building a .NET library for the Stack Overflow API, and I would like to include a function where an input of a display name (username) is converted to the userid. This can be done by using the Users page, but how can this be done programmatically (in C#)? If there aren't any API methods for this, could you explain how it would be possible to screen-scrape the users page for this?

Thanks!

*By the way, if this belongs on StackOverflow (as I'm asking how it can be done programmatically and for sample code), please migrate it. Your help is appreciated!*

Comment: Wait, there's a StackOverflow API? Since when?!

Comment: Here's a link to the unofficial API reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17037/unofficial-stackoverflow-api-reference

Comment: Also, usernames aren't unique. For example, there's this impostor: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134540

Comment: @Eric See my comment on @joshhunt's answer.

Comment: @Maxim: Those are unofficial, not supported AJAX calls used internally on the site. Use at your own risk.

Comment: There is no `migrate-to` close reason, on meta.

Comment: @Eric oh well, at least they work! If there becomes a problem with them, I will change my library. But tackling this UserID problem is hard... any ideas anyone?

Comment: @Lance Really? Does it need to be retagged like that?

Comment: Ok, many people are saying that this belongs on stackoverflow, can anyone migrate it if this is correct? Thanks!

Comment: @UserID:133268 There is no migrate feature for questions that start in Meta. Just post it as a new question on SO. If anybody gives you flack for posting it there, link to this question here.

Comment: @random Im gonna do that when i come back... leaving right now... thanks!

Comment: @Maxim: Many people aren't. Just Lance is. Lance isn't many people. Lance is one people. It's about the non-existant SO API. However, this is a dupe, and Jeff has declined this feature of the API as to now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/api-to-get-userid-from-username

Comment: @MaximZ Probably don't mention the non-existent StackOverflow API, instead just ask about how you're trying to get the IDs based on the DisplayName, but the DisplayNames aren't unique. It could still be a valid question all the same.

Comment: Here's the new question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447840/finding-the-userid-of-a-stackoverflow-user-with-their-display-name-in-c

Answer (score 5):

This would be difficult/impossible seeing the usernames are not unique.

See:

- [Josh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11702/josh)
- [Josh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130712/josh)
- [Josh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130861/josh)
- [Josh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131541/josh)
- [josh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131648/josh)

Comment: Yes, this is a problem, but if it were possible to retrieve all of the userids of users with such a username... that would be cool!

Comment: My brother's name is also Josh.

Comment: This answer is just joshing around.

Comment: I work with a Josh. I don't know if he reads Meta, but if he does, hi Josh!

Comment: Maybe it's josh the same Josh you're joshing with at josh?

Comment: @random: Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo. Amirite?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if everyone were made to name their children with GUIDs

Comment: Malkovich malkovich?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the official API, as the [users method](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=users) supports a **filter** parameter.

Comment: Yup, that's the right way of doing it, nowadays. Back when I originally asked the question, we had an unofficial API with only a few methods... Do you think I should close this question now? :)

Comment: I know, but I thought it made sense to keep it up to date. As for closing, only if it's a duplicate IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old an you already know what I am going to say but....

Find any user by name or email address.

http://stackusers.com/Users/Find