# Search for Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange user by name (not username)

Tags: feature-request, search

I know I can search for Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange users by name by specifying, say,  "user:jackharrison" in the search box. But what if I want a list of all users named "Jack Harrison" and search by name rather than by username?

This related post:

[Stack Overflow API: Finding the UserID of a user with their Display Name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22693/stack-overflow-api-finding-the-userid-of-a-user-with-their-display-name)

references the URL `http://stackusers.com/Users/Find` which is invalid.

Anyone know the solution to this problem.

Comment: You can't search for someone by the real name unless they've chosen to use it as their display name. Which is good...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just go to https://stackoverflow.com/users (or any other Stack Exchange site) and start typing.

The search would find any users with the string you input.

Searching by "Real Name" is impossible, because that's private (only Bob and moderators can see Bob's real name).

Comment: Not if Bob put someone else's name in his private profile area! ;-)