# Embedding UserId in Questions Feeds/API

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api

Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but wouldn't it be helpful to include the userid (unique numeric) as well as the user name in the question feed API/Feed?  Since all of the Unofficial API's require the user id, it would be very helpful for those of us building apps. Having the userid embedded might avoid a lot of extra calls on the site.

Comment: @RichOrr I think you meant "Since all of the Unofficial API's require the user **ID**" (you wrote "name")

Comment: Sorry for the typo - yes, I mean ID.

So instead of:
- <author>
  <name>Jonathan Sampson</name> 
  </author>

We could get:
- <author>
  <name>Jonathan Sampson (123234)</name> 
  </author>

Which could uniquely identify the user that is posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a `<uri>`

```
<author>
    <name>Joe Smith</name>
    <uri>http://example.com/users/12345</uri>
</author>
```

field in the relevant RSS feeds.

Comment: Hmmm... Why not just include a <uri> under <author> that points to their profile?

Comment: @shog ah, good idea. Switching to that.. I tried to find the RSS spec while doing this and couldn't find a simple reference

Comment: that's 'cause it's spelled a-t-o-m ;-P